# How to read a page with an infinite scroll bar using selenium's html unit driver for java?

Tags: java, html, selenium

**FOR EXAMPLE**, if I wanted to find a post on facebook from a year ago using selenium how would I be able to scroll down and then get the text. I have figured out how to scroll using selenium but whenever I try to get elements or the page source it only includes the initial loaded page, nothing that was scrolled down to. I'm not actually using this for facebook, I'm using it for a website that doesn't have java developer tools, stock twits.

Comment: Generally, you are not going to find help on SO for issues that are in direct violation of a site's T&Cs: https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms

Comment: I said for example... I'm using it for a website that has no developer tools for java users, stocktwits. I simply used facebook because that would be the easiest to describe to the most number of people.

Comment: @rmlan Also, please direct me to the text that explains how this is in violation of the T&C's. If i'm not mistaken for the sake of research Facebook allows such things. I have seen a few studies on using Facebook posts in a similar manner.

Comment: Fair enough. I removed my downvote. However, in Section 3.2 the T&Cs state "You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our prior permission." Using selenium to find a Facebook post would fit this definition.

Comment: @rmlan much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic I followed in this example Find a post by its Text Content

```
  Let Allposts

    While timeout
     Get all the currently visible posts which has text in it
      Remove Allposts from currentPosts [So that we dont need to check the same post again]
       And add currentPosts to Allposts[To maintain a list]
         For each post in currentPosts
           check if post's text contains given text
           stop
       scroll to bottom[which invokes ajax call to load more posts]
       //Replace the above with any button like LoadMore or something if scroll dint invoke ajax load
       wait till the page loaded
    do it again
```

This worked perfectly for me I found a post on my wall on my birthday[1 month ago].

It took 20 mins for that [Depends on the no of posts and time of the post it will take more time]

The following will search your facebook news feed for given text

```
public static void fbSearch() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Galen\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("phystem");
    driver.findElement(By.name("pass")).sendKeys("yyy");
    driver.findElement(By.id("loginbutton")).click();
    waitForPageLoaded(driver);
    fbPostSearch(driver, "True Story", 20);//timeOut in Mins
}

public static Boolean fbPostSearch(WebDriver driver, String postContent, int timeOutInMins) {
    Set<WebElement> allPosts = new HashSet<>();
    int totalTime = timeOutInMins * 60000; // in millseconds
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean timeEnds = false;
    while (!timeEnds) {
        List<WebElement> posts = getPosts(driver);
        posts.removeAll(allPosts);//to remove old posts as we already searched it
        allPosts.addAll(posts);//append new posts to all posts
        for (WebElement post : posts) {
            String content = post.getText();
            if (content.contains(postContent)) {
                //this is our element
                System.out.println("Found");
                new Actions(driver).moveToElement(post).build().perform();
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.outline='2px solid #ff0';", post);
                return true;
            }
        }
        scrollToBottom(driver);
        waitForPageLoaded(driver);
        timeEnds = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= totalTime);
    }
    System.out.println("Not Found");
    return false;
}

public static List<WebElement> getPosts(WebDriver driver) {
    //finding Posts which has textContent coz some posts are image only
    return driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div._4-u2.mbm._5v3q._4-u8 div._5pbx.userContent"));
}

private static void scrollToBottom(WebDriver driver) {
    long longScrollHeight = (Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return Math.max("
            + "document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,"
            + "document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,"
            + "document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight);"
    );
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, " + longScrollHeight + ");");
}

public static void waitForPageLoaded(WebDriver driver) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                    "return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(expectation);
}
```

Comment: While it isn't fast enough to be of too much use, this is the first code I've used that works, thanks a bunch!