# get the Friends List of a user on Facebook (using java)

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, graph, htmlunit

I'm trying do draw a graph of users on FB.

I want to obtain the friends list of some users (which I have access because it is my friends or it is public list).

I tried HTMLunit and I succeded in log in and access the friends page :
https://www.facebook.com/userid/friends . 
On this page only 20 friends will automatically load, and you need to scroll or press spacebar to see more.
After some research :

- webClient.getCurrentWindow().setInnerHeight(60000); to have a bigger window but it is not working (suggested here : [How to Scrolldwon a web page using htmlunit or PanthomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779369/how-to-scrolldwon-a-web-page-using-htmlunit-or-panthomjs))
- selenium seems to be very very slow for a high number of pages ([How to read a page with an infinite scroll bar using selenium's html unit driver for java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568035/how-to-read-a-page-with-an-infinite-scroll-bar-using-seleniums-html-unit-driver))
- FB Graph-api does not seems to be a solution for none friend users

I am open to any kind of solution (different idea, library, tool... )

PS: I will not share the data collected, It's for personal use only

Comment: Hi, where you able to find the solution? If you can share the code over git, I see many people have visited this question, it would be helpful. thanks.